# Where was Rey running to on Takodana?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Just after she touches Luke's lightsaber, Maz Kanata tells her to take the Lightsaber, but Rey is visibly upset and refuses, saying:

> I am never touching that thing again, I don't want any part in this.

She then runs out of the castle and into the woods. After running for a while and when stopping for a breather , when she turns around BB8 is following her. She says to BB8:

> - **Rey** - What are you doing? You have to go back...
> - **BB8** - says something...
> - **Rey** - I am leaving...
> - **BB8** - says something...
> - **Rey** - BB8, No you can't , you have to go back your too important... They will help you

I am assuming that she was going to find her way back to Jakku, or was she  intending going somewhere else.

This obviously is not addressed in the movie, so I was looking for an answer most likely from the novelization or something out of universe.

Comment: Video link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

The script (and novels) all seem to broadly concur that Rey was simply running *away* after having suffered a terrible shock. When she finally stopped and thought about it for a few seconds, she realised that she was just going to have to turn around and trudge back to the castle.

Before she could complete her thought about her *next* action (which presumably would have been asking Han to drop her off on Jakku) the First Order fleet turned up.

### **Script**

> [**EXT. FOREST - DAY:** *Rey races through the forest and finally comes to a stop, overwhelmed and exhausted. At an emotional breaking point, she has no idea where to go, who to turn to. Then she HEARS A BEEP -- turns to see BB-8, catching up with her.*]
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens - Official Screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html)</sup></sub>

### **Official Novelisation**

> *Overwhelmed and exhausted both physically and mentally, Rey finally
>   slowed to a halt. Running solved nothing. **Besides, she had nowhere to
>   run to, and she could not run from herself.** A familiar electronic
>   chirp made her turn.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

### **Junior Novelisation**

> *REY finally stopped running, deep in the forest. **She didn’t know why she had been running for so long; she had just felt the need.** Now all she felt was exhaustion.*
>
> ...
>
> *The astromech unit chirped a question of his own. He wanted to know where she intended they go. They? Just because the two of them had traveled together in the past, it didn’t mean they would do so in the future. Finn had reminded her of that.
>
>   But despite her pleas, the little droid refused to leave her. He would go wherever she went, to Jakku and back again if that’s what she wanted.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens: A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

### **Rey's Story**

> *REY RAN THROUGH THE FOREST outside of Maz’s castle. It was too much.
>   She was tired of people she barely knew telling her how she should
>   feel. She just wanted to go home to her simple life on Jakku. It was
>   safe there.*
>
> <sup><sub>[The Force Awakens: Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey%27s_Story)</sub></sup>

Comment: Definitely different to the movie then.